# Higher homotopy groups of wedge of circles.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Using van-kampen theorem, Fundamental group of wedge of n-circles is free group on n-generator. But I don't know how to calculate higher homotopy groups of wedge of spaces, in particular circles. I just came to know that there is some result by Milnor regarding higher homotopy groups of sphere,but I doubt myself that I have understood it.
Any help in this regards will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Help with what, exactly? It is quite nontrivial to compute the homotopy groups of a wedge of spheres (even when the wedge is of only one sphere!) This was done by Peter Hilton in some cases, for example.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez   I was asking only a special case for wedge of n-copies of circle..

Comment: Well, you wrote that you do not know how to compute the groups of a wedge of spaces, and the comment above was meant to show that even for the simplest spaces this is rather difficult .

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez ohh I see.. Anyone thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ is a covering of $Y$, then the higher homotopy groups of $X$ and $Y$ agree. If you like, this is a consequence of the lifting lemmas studied in covering space theory.

One consequence of this is that if the universal cover of a space is contractible, then all of its higher homotopy groups vanish. This is in particular true of a wedge of circles.

Comment: The higher homotopy groups of a wedge of spheres is certainly not zero!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I wrote spheres for circles by mistake, it has been corrected.

Comment: @AreaMan Is universal cover of wedge of circle contractible if we take more than two circles?For wedge of two circle universal cover is caley graph,this is contractible.

Comment: @RipanSaha Yes. It is shown in chapter 1 of Hatcher's textbook that the universal cover of a graph is a graph that is a tree and therefore contractible. And a wedge of circles is certainly a graph.

Comment: ohh I see...thanks...