# If a graph homomorphism induces an isomorphism, is it a homotopy equivalence?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, graph-theory, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

I am taking graphs to potentially have loops and multiple edges. That is, they look like 1-dimensional CW complexes.

If $f\colon\Gamma\to\Delta$ is a graph homomorphism (a.k.a. graph map, map of graphs) where $f_*\colon\pi_1(\Gamma,v)\to\pi_1(\Delta,f(v))$ is an isomorphism then is the same map on the realisation of $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ as CW complexes a homotopy equivalence? The converse is clearly true.

Comment: Isn't $(g \circ f)_* = g_* \circ f_*$?

Comment: But what's $g$?

Comment: Assuming the graphs are connected, isn't this just Whitehead's theorem in the relatively easy case of 1-complexes?

Comment: One way to see this is to use Stallings' foldings; see *John R. Stallings*, topology of finite graphs, Invent. math. 71, 551-565 (1983). The idea is that you can decompose $f=h\circ g$ as a sequence of "folds" $h$ and then an "immersion" $g$. As $f$ is $\pi_1$-injective, the folds used here take two non-loop edges and identify them. Hence, $h(\Gamma)$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Gamma$. By an *immersion* I mean a local injection (injective on vertices). Hence, foldings reduce the result to showing that if $f$ is a local injection with $f_*$ an isomorphism then $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: (which is left as an exercise - you can deduce it from certain results in Stallings' paper, but it is worth doing it "by hand".)

Comment: user1729. As $f$ is $\pi_1$-injective, none of the folds can identify edges which share initial vertices and terminal vertices. It could identify a loop with a non-loop.

Comment: @toe-pose Yes, you are right. But no matter - folds are always homotopies. The sentence is redundant :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you *define* $\pi_1(\Gamma,v)$ as the fundamental group of the CW-realization $\lvert \Gamma \rvert$ of $\Gamma$.

For non-connected graphs your claim is true only if

(1) $f(\Gamma)$ meets all connected components of $\Delta$.

(2) $f_*$ is an isomorphism for *all* $v \in \Gamma$.

The second requirement can be weakened as follows: For each connected component $\Gamma'$ of $\Gamma$, $f_*$ is an isomorphism for some $v \in \Gamma'$.

So let us confine to connected graphs.

Choose maximal trees $T_\Gamma, T_\Delta$ in $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ such that $v \in T_\Gamma, f(v) \in T_\Delta$. It is well-known that the quotient maps $p_\Gamma : \lvert \Gamma \rvert \to \lvert \Gamma \rvert / \lvert T_\Gamma \rvert$ and $p_\Delta : \lvert \Delta \rvert \to \lvert \Delta \rvert / \lvert T_\Delta \rvert$ are pointed homotopy equivalences. Let $q : (\lvert \Gamma \rvert / \lvert T_\Gamma \rvert,\ast) \to (\lvert \Gamma \rvert ,v)$ be a pointed homotopy inverse for $p_\Gamma$. Then $F = p_\Delta f q : (\lvert \Gamma \rvert / \lvert T_\Gamma \rvert,\ast) \to (\lvert \Delta \rvert / \lvert T_\Delta \rvert,\ast)$ is a map which induces an isomorphism on fundamental groups. We have $(\lvert \Gamma \rvert / \lvert T_\Gamma \rvert,\ast) \approx \bigvee_{i \in I} S^1_i$ and $(\lvert \Delta \rvert / \lvert T_\Delta \rvert,\ast) \approx \bigvee_{j \in J} S^1_j$, where $I,J$ are suitable index sets, $S^1_i, S^1_j$ are copies of $S^1$ and $\bigvee$ denotes wedge (= one-point-union). It is well-known that all higher homotopy groups of wegdes of circles are trivial. See for example  [Higher homotopy groups of wedge of circles.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1363011) Therefore $F$ is a weak homotopy equivalence (i.e. induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups $\pi_n$). Since domain and range of $F$ are CW-complexes, $F$ is a homotopy equivalence. This implies that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.