# Generalized wedge sums of multiple $S^n$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Fix $n, m\in\mathbb{N}$. We use $D_n$ to denote the disjoint union of two $(n-1)$-dimensional closed disks. For each $1\leq i \leq m$, we use $S(n, i)$ to denote $S^n$. Then clearly $D_n$ can be embedding into $S(n, 1)$ and we put $O_1 = S(n,1)$. If $m>1$, we then can let $S(n, 2)$ intersect $O_1$ so that the intersection is equal to $D_n$. We use $O_2$ to denote the union of $S(n, 1)$ and $S(n, 2)$ intersecting this way. We can further let $S(n, 3)$ intersect $O_2$ such that again the intersection is equal to (the embedding of) $D_n$. In this way we have $O_m$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

As an example, when $n=1$, $D_1$ only consists of two disjoint points and $O_2$ looks like the following:

[image: O2]

When $n=1$, $O_m$ is $m$ copies of circles glued together at the top and the bottom point. In this case, $O_m$ is a one-dimensional CW complex that consists of two disjoint points and $2m$ many lines. Since any one of the lines is a contractible subcomplex, $O_m$ is homotopic equivalent (via the quotient mapping) to the usual wedge sum of $2m-1$ copies of circles. According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) (or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363011)), when $n=1$, the fundamental group of $O_m$ is the free group with $2m-1$ generators. In general, when $n>1$, what is the fundamental group of $O_m$?

Comment: $D_n$ **is not** contained in $S^n$. It can be embedded, but in many different ways. So do I understand correctly that you take $S^n$, you chose an embedding $D_n\to S^n$ and then you glue $m$ copies of $S^n$ by glueing $D_n$ to $D_n$ component wise?

Comment: Indeed "embedding" is more rigorous, and you are right.

Comment: To attract more attention, the same question is also posted on **MO**: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462416

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your construction is equivalent to the one mentioned in freakish's comment, then your space $O(n, m + 1)$ is obtained from $O(n, m)$ by taking the disjoint union of $O(n, m)$ and a copy of $S^n$, and then identifying a copy of $D^{n - 1} \sqcup D^{n - 1}$ embedded in each. I claim that $O(n, m + 1) \simeq O(n, m) \vee S^n \vee S^1$, so that $O(n, m) \simeq S^n \bigvee_{\text{$(m - 1)$ copies}} (S^1 \vee S^n)$, and so the fundamental group is, as mentioned on the Wikipedia page you linked, the free product of the fundamental groups of the wedge summands. That is, for $n = 1$, the free group on $2m - 1$ generators, and for $n > 1$, the free group on $m$ generators.

The homotopy equivalence is not difficult to see, but would be irritating to write down explicitly. For the case $n = m = 2$, it looks something like this.

Below is a picture of $O(2, 2)$. The $()$-shaped space between the spheres is not part of the surface.

[image: First stage]

A similar space with the copies of $D^1$ replaced by copies of $D^1 \times [0, 1]$, identifying the spheres at the ends of the interval, is homotopy equivalent to $O(2, 2)$.

[image]

These long discs can then be pinched down to copies of the interval $[0, 1]$, and the space in the neighbourhood of the intersection of the sphere pushed around to compensate for the shrinking.

[image]

Finally, we can retract one interval to a point, which we will take to be the basepoint for the wedge. We slide the endpoints of the other interval to the basepoint, which gives us a wedge summand of a circle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers. In your second picture, I suppose the connection between two copies of $S^2$ is a solid cylinder, the same as $D^1\times[0, 1]$. From your second to your third picture, I suppose you shrink both copies of $D^2$ (instead of $D^1$) to a single point. Then why there are two copies of line segments but not just one?

Comment: @Sanae Sorry if the diagram wasn't clear. Each black rectangle is a copy of $D^1 \times [0, 1]$ (when I write $D^1$, I mean the unit disc in $\R^1$). We are then able to shrink each rectangle $D^1 \times [0, 1]$ to $* \times [0, 1]$, which is why there are 2 line segments.

Comment: The surface where two copies of $S^2$ are glued together is only $D^2$, although in your first picture, it looks like two line segments with a "$\big(\big)$" shape thing. Does the "long disc" come from extending $D^2$ when extending the line segment? If yes, I believe the intersection between two $S^2$ has no line segments. If the object, in your second picture, is a solid cylinder with two rectangles, could you explain how you shrink that object to two disjoint line segments?

Comment: @Sanae Maybe it would help to colour in the spheres? In the first picture, the $()$-shaped space is not part of the surface, and in the second picture, the space between the two black horizontal rectangles is not part of the surface.

Comment: Now the first and second picture is clear to me. May I ask, in the second picture, if the space between two rectangles a solid cylinder? If not, how you shrink the whole object to two disjoint line segments?

Comment: @Sanae The area between the two rectangles is not part of the space, and so isn't a solid cylinder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151037/discussion-between-jses-and-sanae).